# Is there a standing policy on what to do with 'How do I cite...' questions?

Tags: discussion, policy

Examples:

- [Referencing a database](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/157147/17423)
- [How to cite a hardware catalog in bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145705/17423)
- [Cite software/libraries using bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132669/17423)

I can't quite articulate my exact thoughts on this, but I'm stuck with the quandary:

- These questions *could be* about how to notate the citation in BibTeX format, in which case they would certainly be on-topic.
- These questions *could be* about how to actually format the citation---they all seem to have that air about them---in which case they are off-topic.

How can we deal with these types of questions that is both *not presumptuous* and *fair*?

Comment: My only idea is to ask OP to add an example of what such a citation would look like when formatted.

Comment: You mean other than answering them? :P

Comment: @percusse Well, yes.  For example, a question such "How do I cite a conference talk in IEEE style?", etc.

Comment: Well, my favourite is commenting by somethi like: _"If your question is about how the citation should look like in the final document, than it's off-topic on the site. On the other hand, if your question is about how to achieve a particular bibitem using `bibtex`, then it's fine, but you need to provide an example of how the result should look like, otherwise we can't really help you."_

Comment: @tohecz And what if the question is _"I have to cite this and this, I have no idea how it should like, and I expect that Bib(La)TeX knows that instead of me"_?

Comment: @marczellm Then he should ask his more experienced colleague, or go to academia.SE, math.SE, physics.SE, biology.SE or whaever site corresponds to his field, and ask there how should such a bibitem look like. Then he can come here again with the specifications.